# MySQL - Filtering table based on most current dates

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

My first post on stackoverflow please be gentle! 
I have a MySQL (5.5.24) Database (WAMP Setup) with a table with records like this

```
Person_ID     R_Date    

137           2013-01-01    
137           2013-02-01
137           2013-03-15  
168           2013-01-01
168           2013-02-01
168           2013-03-21
172           2013-01-01
172           2013-02-01
172           2013-03-27
```

However I would like to just have 1 record for each Person_ID using the most recent/current R_Date.   
So the results would look like this:

```
Person_ID    R_Date

137          2013-03-15
168          2013-03-21
172          2013-02-27
```

I have had difficulty searching for answers as I'm not sure of the terminology, it is possibly something really simple. 
 
It is possible to get this result using PHP While loops combined with multiple MySQL queries but I'm after a pure MySQL solution if it's possible.
Maybe the results I am after are achievable with subqueries? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Person_ID, MAX(R_Date) as 'R_Date' FROM TableName GROUP BY Person_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well and was exactly what I was after. I had experimented with MAX() and GROUP BY before but must have got muddled.

Comment: No issues. :) Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSONTABLE a
WHERE R_Date = ( SELECT MAX(R_Date) 
                 FROM PERSONTABLE b 
                 WHERE a.Person_ID = b.Person_ID
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Person_ID, MAX(R_Date) FROM <YourTable> GROUP BY Person_ID
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the MAX(R_Date) need an alias? eg: -   SELECT Person_ID, MAX(R_Date) as r_date FROM <YourTable> GROUP BY Person_ID;